# How to move data automatically from row to other row in Google Sheet for multiple tab sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-formula

I have 1 File of Gogle Sheet that contain many sheet tabs with different data, but same order to organize it. How to do this automatically so I can save time instead copy paste one by one for each tab?

The order is:

1. Move Data from C4 to H4
2. Move Data from C6-C15 to G5-G14
3. Move Data from D4 to H15
4. Move Data from D6-D15 to G16-G25

Thanks